# How to Toggle (or Scale) to reduce a DIV's vertical size (but only to 30% of initial height)

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, scale, effect

So I've got a DIV (a map) that goes across the width of the page, but i'd like to have a button users can click to "Hide/Unhide" the DIV that will basically do three things when clicked:

1. scale the vertical height of the div to 25% of the original height...
2. Change the DIV to have opacity .3 so its faded when at its reduced height...
3. Revert back to normal height & opacity (1) when clicked again

Here's what I've got so far: Currently it only scales down to the correct vertical height

Really appreciate the help...

```
<!-- JQUERY STUFF ADDED IN THE HEAD-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- THE CODE -->
<div id="map">
    Map Content Is Here
</div>

<p class="hidemap">HIDE MAP</p>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("p.hidemap").click(function () {
    $("#map").effect("scale", { percent: 25, direction: 'vertical' }, 500);
    });

   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var orig_height = $('#map').height();

$('.hidemap').click(function()
{
    if($('#map').height() == orig_height)
    {
        var new_height = Math.floor(orig_height * .25) + 'px';
        var new_opacity = '.3';
    }
    else
    {
        var new_height = orig_height + 'px';
        var new_opacity = '1';
    }
    $('#map').animate(
    {
        height: new_height,
        opacity: new_opacity
    },1000);
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/X4NaV/

Comment: Thanks a lot man.  One thing though:  If you look at your working example above & change the desired height from .25 to .01 you'll see that the content within the div still remains (If you type a lot more text its easier to see...but I'd also like any content within the div to be cut off (or reduced from the bottom).   REally appreciate the help

Comment: You can't do that. Divs have a min height of like 18px. If you want it to go away completely you can try $('#map').slideUp() and $('#map').slideDown()

Comment: Ah - actually the 18 px is fine I'm reducing it down to probably 150 or so pixels...but the problem is I've got my map within a div (so I'm actually reducing a div that holds a map (<iframe> from google maps)...but when i do it the map pops out of the bottom and stays at the original height (while the div containing the map is reduced to 25%).

Comment: add overflow:hidden; to the #map css

Comment: Not sure if that comment made sense but a good example is if you went back to your working example and put in a whole paragraph of text that was like 50 px tall & tried it again, thats basically whats happening to my map.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help - please click the check mark next to the answer to "accept" the answer as workable.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Alien's, here you have:

```
<div id="map" style="overflow:hidden"> <!-- Look at the style -->
    Map Content Is Here <br>
    This is the seccond line
</div>

<p class="hidemap">HIDE MAP</p>
```

The script:

```
var orig_height = $('#map').height();

$('p.hidemap').click(function()
{
    var new_height = orig_height;
    var new_opacity = 1;
    if($('#map').height() == orig_height){
        new_height = Math.floor(orig_height * .01);
        new_opacity = .3;
    }
    $('#map').animate({
        height: new_height,
        opacity: new_opacity
    }, 2000);
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers